# QR code specs, how can i reach it out to make it scan from mobile phones

Tags: size, qr-code, scanning

I need to store very long text in a qrcode, is there any link to understand which are main qrcode types and sizes available?

I tryed storing long text in a qrcode, but seems it is too much full, cause my android scanner can't scan it.

As i know it can store 4kb so i must be able to store my text cause it doesn't go up to the 4kb.

Strange later i will post my QR so someone could better help me, hoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with QR Codes containing a lot of information is that as they increase in size, it becomes harder and harder to scan them using a smartphone camera. For example a QR Code such as: [image: this]

(which is the maximum size for a QR Codes) is nearly impossible to scan using a smartphone, simply because the camera resolution is not sufficient for most algorithms to be able to decode it. On this example, the QR Code is 177x177 modules, so even using HD resolution (1280x720px) and scanning close enough to make the QR Code fill the whole image width, each module will not be more than roughly 4px, which makes decoding very hard.

This doesn't solve your problem, but I hope it explains it!

Comment: yep your clear, that is what i thought tryng scanning codes like that on my mobile :(